# Is it still possible to order the reinstall disk for a MacBook 2007?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

I want to order the reinstall disk for MacBook 2007.

Comment: The question is what Operating System do you want?

Comment: If you can get to an Apple Store, you can ask them to just install whatever OS X you want. Note: it will be a fresh install so make sure you have a backup of whatever is on your computer. Another Note: you must have 4 GB of ram to install any OS beyond Snow Leopard. (Snow leopard requires 2GB)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is the restore disk that came with the computer. If so your best bet is to just call the Apple Store and speak to a sales rep. Those kind of things are generally unavailable on the web site or stores but are available through Apple itself.

Apple Contact info [here.](http://www.apple.com/contact/)